# EF 5 TPT inherit abstract class issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

In my Project I have a Base class which should be mapped to database :

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    protected EntityBase()
    {
        UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        LastModified = DateTime.Now;

    }

    #region Properties
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual long CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual long UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```

and some of the entities have shared properties, so I created another base for those entities which shouldn't be mapped and the properties even shared ones should be mapped in it's own entity :

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ApplicationEntityBase : EntityBase
{

    #region Properties
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```

now the problem is when I try to create database Entity Framework creates about 20 table for Entity Base !

the mappings are :

```
 public class EntityMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityBase>
{
    public EntityMapping()
    {

        ToTable("Entity");

        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(e => e.UniqueId).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.Version).IsRequired().IsRowVersion();
        Property(e => e.CreationDate).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.LastModified).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.Order);
        Property(e => e.CreatedById).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.UpdatedById).IsRequired();

    }
}
```

and example of Application Entity mapping is :

```
 public abstract class ApplicationMappingBase<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
   where TEntity : ApplicationEntityBase
{
    protected ApplicationMappingBase()
    {
        //Map(m => m.ToTable(typeof(TEntity).Name));

        Property(e => e.Title).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.Description);
        Property(e => e.Icon);
    }
}

public class ActionMapping : ApplicationMappingBase<Entities.Core.Security.Action>
{
    public ActionMapping()
        : base()
    {
        Map(m => m.ToTable("Action"));

        Property(e => e.IsGeneral).IsRequired();
        Property(e => e.OnBefore).IsOptional();
        Property(e => e.OnAfter).IsOptional();
        Property(e => e.DoneMessage).IsOptional();
        HasMany(d => d.Activities).WithRequired(t => t.Action);
    }
}
```

would you please tell me what's wrong with my code? am I doing something wrong?
I read lots of articles including http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx but nothing found same as my situation